# How to write Blob to a local file?

Tags: javascript, html

I have read the nice article
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/xhr2/

It uses HTML5 FileSystem API and FileWriter to achieve writing Blob to local files.

However, my browser Safari (currently 7.0.5) doesn't support `requestFileSystem` and `FileWriter`. (I have tested with Chrome. It doesn't support either.)

I also searched online but there didn't seem something like "formal answers".

Another question is why reading local files to browser is simple (using `FileReader`), but writing to local files doesn't seem symmetric, especially in the new html5 standard.

Comment: Writing to local files poses more of a potential security risk, and it has a newer API besides. However, forcing downloads has always worked.

Answer (score 2):

In webkit (Chrome and Safari), you can in fact use the FileSystem api via a vendor prefix:

```
window.webkitRequestFileSystem
```

And `FileWriter` isn't directly exposed to JavaScript anyway.

For non-supporting browsers (which is many): https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js will help.

---

Have you considered forcing a download the old-fashioned way (more compatibility)? Read the `Blob` as a Data URI, then change the content-type of the URI to a value that forces a download. Downside: no specifying the file name and tedious.

```
var reader = new FileReader;
reader.onload = function() {
    window.open(this.result.replace(/data:.+?\/[^;]+/, "data:application/octet-stream"));
};
reader.readAsDataURL(my_blob);
```

Comment: I tried [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js) and it didn't show the dialog like `<input type="file"/>` does. Do I misunderstand anything? Or is it platform-dependent? (Mine is Mac OS/Safari)

Comment: Btw, I couldn't find the output file in the local file system either.

Comment: @RedBeanPieLarry: The file would be in your downloads folder (or depending on your browser's settings, you'd be prompted where to save it). And there's no way to show a file saving dialog lile that unless your browser *natively* supports the API or its settings cause it to ask you where to save downloads.